# fail to use aiomysql in mutithreading mode

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I wanted to use aiomysql in mutithreading mode. Then it failed. Here is my code.

```
import asyncio
import aiomysql

from threading import Thread

def start_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

async def create_pool(loop, **kw):
    global __pool
    __pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(
        host=kw.get('host', 'localhost'),
        port=kw.get('port', 3306),
        user=kw['user'],
        password=kw['password'],
        db=kw['db'],
        charset=kw.get('charset', 'utf8'),
        autocommit=kw.get('autocommit', True),
        maxsize=kw.get('maxsize', 10),
        minsize=kw.get('minsize', 1),
        loop=loop
    )

async def select():
    global __pool
    async with __pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor(aiomysql.DictCursor) as cur:
            print('ok here')
            await cur.execute('select * from test')
            print('failed here')
            rs = await cur.fetchall()
            print('rows returned: %s' % len(rs))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
t = Thread(target=start_loop, args=(new_loop,))
loop.run_until_complete(create_pool(loop, user='user', password='password', db='test'))
t.start()
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(select(), new_loop)
```

'ok here' can be printed while 'failed here' can't. So it fails in "await cur.execute('select * from test')". It'll work if I use create_pool and select in one thread. So it confuses me why it fails in multithreading mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you running `create_pool()` in one event loop and `select()` in another? It seems like asking for trouble from the very start. The very point of asyncio is that you have a single event loop that multiplexes all your tasks.

Comment: I just ignored it. Thank you.